# How can I make 256 Tkinter objects easily?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to make a 16x16 grid of buttons. Is there a simple and short way to assign a unique variable to each one of them. Right now, I'm using this, but it seems wonky (for example, I'm having issues with `destroy()` function):

```py
coords = [["x01y01","x01y02"...]
          ...
          [..."x16y15","x16y16"]]

for i in range(16):
     for j in range(16):
          coords[i][j] = Button(...)
```

Comment: Why in the world would you *want* to have a separate variable for each Button?  That would be a nightmare - you couldn't do anything with the Buttons without duplicating your code 256 times.  What you want is to put them all into some sort of container, that you can loop over - likely options are a list of lists (you're basically doing that now, it's just that the initial values you're putting in `coords` are pointless), or a dictionary with keys being a `(x, y)` tuple.

Comment: I never used tkinter before so I haven't realized buttons don't need to be individually assigned to a variable. What you said works great. Thank you.